# Receiving "no return tags (sitemaps)" error in Google Search Console should I add hreflang="en" to sitemap XML file?

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, internationalization, hreflang

Under my **Google Search Console** I'm receiving a **'es' - no return tags (sitemaps)** error for:

- **Originating URL:** `/en/about-us/testimonials`
- **Alternate URL:** `/es/about-us/testimonials`

---

And I have my **sitemap XML file** setup like the following:

```
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.example.com/es/about-us/testimonials" />
  <lastmod>2016-07-11T00:00:00Z</lastmod>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/es/about-us/testimonials</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.example.com/es/about-us/testimonials" />
  <lastmod>2016-07-11T00:00:00Z</lastmod>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

However, should I also be including the following **hreflang="en"** in my **sitemap XML file** to avoid this issue?

```
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.example.com/es/about-us/testimonials" />
  <lastmod>2016-07-11T00:00:00Z</lastmod>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/es/about-us/testimonials</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.example.com/es/about-us/testimonials" />
  <lastmod>2016-07-11T00:00:00Z</lastmod>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you  need to include **both languages for each entry** in the *sitemap*: the url you are specifying in the `loc` item and every alternate language version of the page.

Also the `hreflang="x-default"` is used only for auto-redirecting homepages or selectors, so in your case it seems that both pages have a specific language: `en` and `es`, it should be written with **hreflang="en"** instead of `x-default` like this:

```
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.example.com/es/about-us/testimonials" />
  <lastmod>2016-07-11T00:00:00Z</lastmod>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/es/about-us/testimonials</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/en/about-us/testimonials" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.example.com/es/about-us/testimonials" />
  <lastmod>2016-07-11T00:00:00Z</lastmod>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you...I thought for **x-default** I had to include this in my Sitemap XML so Google knows to use this page as the default page for all other languages that I don't have translations for?  So for example, if I didn't have French listed in my Sitemap XML it would show French users my **x-default** link in the Google France search engine?

Comment: @olimits7 __x-default__ is used when the page doesn’t target a specific language or locale, so it would be helpful if you have a generic `https://www.example.com/`. In  this case you have the content in two languages, if you enter a query search in English, in Google France, it would return the English version of the web page.

Comment: Ok, my website doesn't have a generic https://www.example.com/ , if you type that in to my site you get redirected to https://www.example.com/en ; so this is my default site.  So should I change **x-default** to **en** in my Sitemap XML?  Or should I add another line in my Sitemap XML pointing to the same URL for both **x-default** and **en**?  Ty.

Comment: I would just change the `x-default` for `en`, not using `x-default`. Then send the sitemap to webmaster tools to verify it.